# How can I use ROS data to create a GUI?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

My robot is a quad walker with Kinect and controlled by Arduino. The ROS will read the data from Kinect and then record the related x, y ordinate. But I have no idea for how can I use those data to create a node in graphic user interface. Should I use TCP/IP method send those data to client and build the GUI in that computer. Or I should use Matlab or Labview to build the GUI in Ubuntu directly. Which method should be easier.

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56122/how-can-i-use-ros-data-to-create-a-gui??/) by [littleming](https://answers.ros.org/users/4282/littleming/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-02-24**:
I want to understand what is behind this goal " But I have no idea for how can I use those data to create a node in graphic user interface."
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS already provides a GUI for that: [rviz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-24**:
Also, http://ros.org/wiki/rqt is nice, if you want to add your own custom information.